Cannot find name 'myFun' (defined in included file "my-funs.js")
The function myFun is defined in the included file:
<include src="my-funs.js"><script>

The include file has // @ts-check and a JSDoc comment for the function:
/**
 * 
 * @param {*} type 
 * @param {*} attrib 
 * @param {*} inner 
 * @returns {*}
 */
function myFun(type, attrib, inner) {
  // code
}

I am using VS Code and it tells me the error in the title.
I expected JSDoc/TypeScript to find the declaration of myFun, but obviously I was wrong.
What am I missing?

EDIT:
Thanks for any effort. I am beginning to realize that this is a bit complicated.
I see the same problem with a var dummy variable.
The JavaScript code is executed without any errors. So JavaScript knows about the declarations, but TypeScript do not know about them.
It looks like a mismatch, a little bit similar to this old issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43576

<script src="my-funs.js"></script> maybe ?

@fedeghe Thanks. No that line is included. (The JavaScript code runs ok.)

/**
 * 
 * @param {string} type 
 * @param {string} attrib 
 * @param {string} inner 
 * @returns {string}
 */
function myFun(type, attrib, inner) {
  
}

try to add types instead of * since typescript relies on type annotations

Thanks, but the types here are a bit complicated and I have absolutely no use for that check right now. (The function will just error if not correct. And I will notice that.)
